# Code standard enforcer for Visual C++

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

I am looking for a tool to enforce our C++ coding standards.  We work in Visual C++ on MS Windows.

1. Must run on MS Windows on Visual C++ source code
2. Must flag deviations from our standard
3. Must be configurable to enforce our style and naming conventions at least
4. Must not cost much over $300/developer/year for 20 developers
5. It would be really nice if it could integrate well with Visual Studio
6. It would be really nice if it could be easily set up to run automatically
7. It would be nice if it integrated well with Subversion, Git, SmartBear's Collaborator and Cruise Control

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you take a look at Gimpel's [PC-Lint](https://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm):

1. Must run on MS Windows on Visual C++ source code - *It actually runs from the command line on **just  about** any windows platform processing C/C++ code.*
2. Must flag deviations from our standard - *That depends a lot on your standard if you are using selected parts of MISRA you can tailor it for that simply however if you have a rule that all functions must be named for characters from the Dr Zuse books you are probably out of luck.*
3. Must be configurable to enforce our style and naming conventions at least - *Again it depends on what they are.*
4. Must not cost much over $300/developer/year for 20 developers - *A one-location, 10 user LAN license is $3500.  Each additional user is $300.  So not far over.*
5. It would be really nice if it could integrate well with Visual Studio *There are integrations available for most versions of VS*
6. It would be really nice if it could be easily set up to run automatically *It is run from a batch file so can be integrated with CI tools such as Jenkins*
7. It would be nice if it integrated well with Subversion, Git, SmartBear's Collaborator and Cruise Control - *You can set most VCS systems up to run it as a pre-commit hook and to refuse to commit if the code is worse than before.*

Comment: Looks to me a bit of a dead product, does it get updated still to new standards (I couldn't find any reference)?

Comment: The sales team was quite responsive to my request for an evaluation copy.

Comment: @DavidThornley That is good to hear.

Comment: Isn't this a static analysis tool? And it seems to be of a rather poor quality. They don't provide any realistic examples and they don't properly support C++11 (and therefore it is not compatible with recent versions of VS).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com/)? a pretty cool static analysis tool, easy to write your own coding rules using [CQLinq](https://www.cppdepend.com/cqlinq).